# How to create a Webm Animated Image with ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, animated-gif, webm

I am succesfully creating an 3 seconds long / 6 frame per second animated image file from a video file using the following code with ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg.input(video_url, ss=0).filter('scale', motion_width, -1)
.filter('fps', fps=6, round='up')
.output(out_filesystem_motion_filename, vframes=18, loop=0)
.overwrite_output().run()
```

This works fine with when I provide the output filename a gif : "thumbnail.gif" yet when I provide the output filename as a webm file "thumbnail.webm", chrome plays the output file as a video rather than an animated image file.

How can I make Chrome to show the webm file as an animated image ?